# Setting window top without scrolling in page transition nextjs

Tags: next.js

Is it possible on page mount (useEffect) setting the window scroll top position without the scroll effect?
right now in nextjs i have pages which behaves like SPA, am persisting the scroll position of each page in react Context. below is my useEffect in all the pages.

```
useEffect(() => {

  window.scrollTo({ top: scrollPosition[page].current.scrollPos, behavior: 'auto' });

  const handleScrollPos = () => {
    scrollPosition[page].current.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
  };
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollPos);
    return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScrollPos);
  };
}, []);
```

the problem is, if am in page **Home** with top value **400**, switch to page **about**
the page about should start from **0** but right now its scrolling from **400 to 0** in **about** page

PS: somehow this implementation is working without scroll behavoiur in safari, just in chrome this is happening

Comment: Do you have CSS to enable smooth scrolling?

Comment: @juliomalves found that one global css had scroll-behavior: smooth;
removed it and its working as expected.